# inserting a value to mongodb from python result in werid number?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, database

I want to perform a very simple task with pymongo and mongodb. I'm running the latest pymongo and mongodb 2.1.1 on my raspberry pi.

The problem is, I run the following code on python to insert the value:

```
myDATA1 = {"sensor_id":3, "value":float(str(w1_temp)), "date":datetime.datetime.utcnow()}
post_id = db.sensor.insert(myDATA1)
```

Note the line `float(str(w1_temp))`. I also tried with `w1_temp` and it still don't work. I just wanted to be sure w1_temp is formated as a float number, and that it can be stored on mongodb. But this is not the question. The line

```
print myDATA1
```

on python will generate this:

```
{'date': datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 4, 18, 3, 55, 923904), 'sensor_id': 3, 'value': 1.937, '_id': ObjectId('5134e20b72ab8a6491111a8a')}
```

On mongodb, I see this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5134e20b72ab8a6491111a8a"), "date" : ISODate("2013-03-04T18:03:55.923Z"), "sensor_id" : 3, "value" : -2.960244045726579e-47 }
```

as you can see, the value of `value` is totally different!!! WHY?

thanks

Comment: I forgot to mention, Inserting numbers without decimals **do work** very well...

Comment: I just tryed that and it worked out fine. I suspect the problem is in a different part of your code.

Comment: It should work! do you think maybe the variable `w1_temp` has a strange formmating/type?

Comment: If I write in python this: `w1_temp = 2`, `myDATA1 = {"sensor_id":3, "value":float(str(w1_temp)), "date":datetime.datetime.utcnow()}`, then I get the desired result, but if I set `w1_temp = 2.1`, the result is again broken.

Comment: What's your query to pull the product from the db?

Comment: I think the error is in mongodb. On the mongo console, if I enter `db.sensor.insert({'sensor_id': 3, 'value': 1.937})`, then I get: `{ "_id" : ObjectId("5134e8446d8bf42ab2b10d8d"), "sensor_id" : 3, "value" : -2.960244045726579e-47 }`

Comment: How are you installing on a raspberry pi?  Have you tried on another machine?  Works as normal on my intel mac.

Comment: the problem is on the terminal... it looks like with python I can isert the value correctly, but I can't "display" it on the termianl. I tried on another machine running same mongo v 2.1.1, and the same happens. I can't even type `a=1.1`, it will show a stupid number :-) ---> case closed.